# Is there any way to not load an element with knockout conditionals?

Tags: knockout.js

I have a list of items that can be one of two types - depending on the type, I need to use a different styling/layout.  What I'm doing right now is iterating over all items and displaying both "templates" for each one, but displaying only one template per item depending on how the type() evaluates.  This seems inelegant because I really only need one template per item - half of the markup on the page will never be visible.

Is there any way I can only load the markup I need for these items, without breaking them into two different arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep,  something like this should work for you.

```
<div data-bind="foreach: yourArray">

    <div data-bind="if: isTypeOne">
        <div>template for type one</div>
    </div>

    <div data-bind="if: isTypeTwo">
        <div>template for type two</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

This way, the template inside each conditional tag is only generated when it evaluates true.

Comment: very cool, I had no idea I could use 'if' like that.  Thank you!

Comment: Yep, be sure to check out the Knockout docs also, they're quite good.

Comment: A warning against excessive use of if/ifnot: these statements will actually add and remove elements from the DOM. This can cause all kinds of problems if you are also using jQuery against elements in the affected section.  I prefer Jeff Mercado's answer because of this.

Answer (score 2):

What you should do is put your two "templates" into *real* templates and add a computed observable which decides which template to use.  This will be especially helpful if your templates are pretty complicated or you have many different templates to potentially display.

e.g., suppose you had a user:

```js
function User(user) {
    this.name = ko.observable(user.name);
    this.isSuperUser = ko.observable(user.isSuperUser);

    // this chooses which template to use        
    this.userTemplate = ko.computed(function () {
        return this.isSuperUser()
            ? "userTemplate-superuser"
            : "userTemplate-user";
    }, this);
}
```

Given a list of users, you can then show the appropriate template based on what the `userTemplate` is.

```html
<div data-bind="foreach: users">
    <div data-bind="template: userTemplate"></div>
</div>

<script id="userTemplate-superuser" type="text/html">
    <div class="su">
        Greetings super user <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
    </div>
</script>
<script id="userTemplate-user" type="text/html">
    <div class="u">
        Greetings regular user <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
    </div>
</script>
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jeff1203/Rhp42/)